# Can not retrieve data from MySql database

Tags: vb.net

when I run the code, I have an error message that says: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I would like to create a code that verify credentials that are in the database. If the user that not enter valid information, an error message appears. Here is my code:

```
    'Declare variables
    Dim pwd, username As String
    Dim dbpwd, dbUsername As String

    'Get credentials variables
    username = Me.username.Text
    pwd = Me.TextBox2.Text


    Dim objConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim objDataset As New DataSet
    Dim objDataAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlConn As String


    If username <> "" And pwd <> "" Then

        objConn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password= ;database=mayombe_mdcs")
        objConn.Open()
        sqlConn = "select agent_id, Password from password where agent_id = " & username & ""


        Try
        objDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlConn, objConn)
        objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataset)

        ' intRowNumber = sqlR
        dbUsername = objDataset.Tables("password").Rows(1).Item(2)

        ' dbpwd = objDataset.Tables("password").Rows(1).Item(1)
        'WriteLine (dbUsername )
        'Force users to enter credentiasl

        objConn.Close()
        'Force user to enter true credentials
        If pwd = dbpwd And username = dbUsername Then
           open form

            Me.Close()

        End If
        Catch ex As Exception
         strMsg As String
        Prompt message that tells the user that credentials entered are not correct.
        strMsg = String.Format("One of the following is incorrect: {0}* Username entered {0}* Password entered.", Environment.NewLine)
        MessageBox.Show(strMsg, "Warning")
        End Try
```

Comment: I don't know anything about vb.net, but I recommend saying ..WHERE agent_id = '" vb.net code "'" (Don't forget the ' sign in the query)

Comment: That not a problem. there must be another.

Comment: On which line did you get the exception?

Comment: On this line: dbUsername = objDataset.Tables("password").Rows(1).Item(2)

Comment: Here is the Exeption message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things wrong in your code.

First, if agent_id is a varchar field you need to use single quotes around the value used in the where clause, but it is better to avoid this problem and use a [parameterized query](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/parameterized-query-and-sql-injection-attacks/).

Second, if you find something then you should refer to the first row using index 0 and to the second column using index 1. Your code assumes that indexing of an array starts at index 1 but this is not true in the NET world. Arrays always start at index 0.

I would try to rewrite your code as this

```
objDataset = new Dataset()
sqlConn = "select agent_id, Password from password where agent_id = @usr"
using objConn = New MySqlConnection(....)
    objConn.Open()
    Try
    objDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlConn, objConn)
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", username)
    objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataset)
    if objDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
       dbUsername = objDataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
    End If
End Using
```